# how to upgrade from magento 2.3.0 to 2.3.1 steps (composer)

Tags: upgrade, magento2.3, composer

I want to upgrade my magento to the latest version. what are the steps to upgrade from Magento 2.3.0 to Magento 2.3.1 via composer?

Answer (score 2):

upgrade Magento 2.3.0 to 2.3.1 over composer:
the below steps should work.

**step 1** require latest version 2.3.1

```
composer require magento/product-community-edition=2.3.1 --no-update
```

**step 2** apply updates

```
composer update
```

**step 3** clean magento cache

```
bin/magento cache:clean
```

**step 4** clear var and generated folders

```
rm -rf <Magento install dir>/var/cache/*
rm -rf <Magento install dir>/var/page_cache/*
rm -rf <Magento install dir>/generated/code/*
```

step 5 update databse schema and data

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
```

step 6 disable maintenance mode

```
php bin/magento maintenance:disable
```

step 7 apply static content (depending on your languages)

```
bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f nl_BE
bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f nl_NL
bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f en_US
```

that's it.

Comment: I have to mention one more command `bin/magento cache:enable` because my caches was disabled after update via composer.